# how to find and edit any joomla content using the frontend url

Tags: joomla

How can I find this front-end URL(http://www.mediware.com/contact-mediware) in Joomla?

I have tried appending the ?tp=1 and that does not tell me where it is to edit.
I have tried finding it via ftp under the directory mod_menu.
I have tried finding it in Joomla back-end under the menu manager and menu items.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "find" it? Joomla is a CMS. There are not actual pages in files, the content is stored in a database. You probably need to login to the site administrator and go to that component to edit it.

Comment: Unless it is a component, it will be in the administrator in Content->articles

Comment: how do i find out what component it is?